# R: 'Missing Value where True/False needed'

Tags: r

So I know this has been asked before, but from what I've searched I can't really find an answer to my problem. I should also add I'm relatively new to R (and any type of coding at all) so when it comes to fixing problems in code I'm not too sure what I'm looking for.

My code is:

```
education_ge <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2, nrow=1))
colnames(education_ge) <- c("Education","Genetic.Engineering")

for (i in 1:nrow(survey))
if (survey[i,12]=="Bachelors")  
education_ge$Education <- survey[i,12]
```

To give more info, 'survey' is a data frame with 12 columns and 26 rows, and the 12th column, 'Education', is a factor which has levels such as 'Bachelors', 'Masters', 'Doctorate' etc.

This is the error as it appears in R:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(survey))
  if (survey[i,12]=="Bachelors")  
    education_ge$Education <- survey[i,12]
Error in if (survey[i, 12] == "Bachelors") education_ge$Education <- survey[i,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check if you have `NA` instead of a character in `servey[i, 12]`

Comment: Can you please tell what is education_ge$Education. . Mayb what u can do is save all the "bachelor" entries in an array and then outside the loop, you can save the array in the dataframe. Please let me know whats education_ge$Education and your purpose of the code in short so that I can provide you with the code

Comment: So I have a df, 'survey'. it has 12 columns, such as education, ethnicity, age, comfort with genetic engineering etc. What I want to do is select those rows in which education is 'Bachelors', and put their education level, and comfort with genetically engineered products, into a new dataframe, 'education_ge' which I was subsetting into the Education column (hence education_ge$Education).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore any records with missing values and get on with your analysis, try inserting this at the beginning:

```
survey <- survey[ complete.cases(survey), ]
```

It basically finds the indexes of all the rows where there are no NAs anywhere, and then subsets survey to have only those rows.

For more information on subsetting, try reading this chapter: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

The command:

```
sapply(survey,function (x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

will show you how many NAs you have in each column. That might help your data cleaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried this and it results in education_ge having only a single row, with 'Bachelors' in the correct column. I would expect to have about seven rows.

Comment: Sounds like your data needs cleaning then. It is not a lot of data, so it should be easily done. In this case I would consider using a spreadsheet to do it because it is so small.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sub<-subset(survey,survey$Education=="Bachelors") 

education_ge$Education<-sub$Education
```

Let me know if this helps.